# cx_freeze executable runs from cmd but not on click

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

After dealing with all .egg issues with cx_freeze, I'm having issues running the .exe on click or from .bat.  If I run the .exe from cmd, it runs perfectly.  But if I click on the .exe, I get a popup list of errors that goes off the page.

I've tried changing the `base=None` and `base=Win32GUI` to no avail.

I'm running python 3.4 from and Anaconda environment.  The errors make it look like on running, the .exe is looking in the normal python path, but there are references the the correct python path as well.

Any experiences with this?

Error from clicking. This goes off the screen so I can't see the final error: 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2pbv.png)

Comment: To add to this, I can only run the exe from cmd when I am in the 3.4 environment. What is the point of building the exe if I can only run with the right version of python running?

Comment: I was able to resolve the problems I had using pyinstaller rather than cx_freeze.